# Can おいてない act as a contraction of おいてほかにない

Tags: grammar, meaning, conjugations

> 仕事疲れのストレス解消方法は、仕事を少し忘れてみること、それをおいてないでしょう。散歩や旅行などで気分転換を図りましょう。

The above sentence appeared in my grammar textbook in the same chapter that introduced the ～をおいてほかにない grammar point with a "is the best in comparison" meaning.

This meaning seems to fit the above sentence in that 仕事を少し忘れてみること is the best way to reduce work-related stress but I can't seem to find anything about をおいてない specifically on the internet or in my grammar books. Is the ほかに simply omitted or does it have a different meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This おく means "to exclude" or "to put aside". In this sense, it is commonly written 措く in kanji. (デジタル大辞泉 and jisho.org have a distinct entry for 措く, while 明鏡国語辞典 explains this as part of 置く.)

> #### [措く](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%8E%AA%E3%81%8F/)
>
> 《「置く」と同語源》
> ２ 除く。のける。さしおく。「君を―・いて適任者はいない」「何はさて―・き」

> #### おく【置く】
>
> 《「…を━・いて」の形で》…を除いて。…をさしおいて。
> 「彼を━・いて（＝彼以外に）適任者はいない」
> 「<sup>▽</sup>措く」とも。
> (明鏡国語辞典 第二版)

So ～を措いてない literally means "excluding ～, there is nothing (remaining)". ほかに is optional because it just means "else".